# Fat free Framework Parameterized queries LIKE

Tags: mysql, database, pdo, sql-like, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to get a query with a LIKE comparison going in Fat Free Framework.

```
$db->exec('SELECT * FROM ideas WHERE name LIKE %:idea%',array(':idea'=>$idea));
```

That's the query.

The error I'm getting is

> PDOStatement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'unit'%' at line 1`

Seems like the prepared statement inserts quotes between the placeholders (`%`), which leads to an error. Can I somehow write this in another way or prevent the quotes from appearing?

Comment: Load the `%` into the `$idea` variable rather than in the raw query part So `$idea = "%$idea%";`

Comment: Or `LIKE :idea', array(':idea'=>'%'. $idea . '%')`

Comment: @RiggsFolly wow, easier then expected.. thank you! :)